# What is the most efficient MySQL query to find all entries that start with a number?

Tags: mysql, performance

In a database that has over 1 million entries, occasionally we need to find all rows that have a column `name` that starts with a number.

This is what currently is being used, but it just seems like there may be a more efficient manner in doing this.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '0%' OR name LIKE '1%' OR name ...`

etc...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could *maybe* do something clever with casting to an integer if your server is not in strict mode: `1ABCDEF` should become `1`. Just a fleeting idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select * from table where your_field regexp '^[0-9]'

Comment: This plus an index on the name attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Hey,
you should add an index with a length of 1 to the field in the db. The query will then be significantly faster.

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`table` ADD INDEX `indexName` ( `column` ( 1 ) )
```

Felix

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the indexes on the table aren't being used efficiently (if at all)
Since this is a char field of some type, and if this is the primary query on this table, you could restructure your indexes (and my mysql knowledge is a bit short here, somebody help out) such that this table is ordered (clustered index in ms sql) by this field, thus you could say something like

```
select * from mytable where name < char(57) and name > char(47)
```

Do some testing there, I'm not 100% on the details of how mysql would rank those characters, but that should get you going.

Another option is to have a new column that gives you a true/false on "starts_with_number".  You could setup a trigger to populate that column.  This might give the best and most predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE IF( LEFT( name, 1) = '#', 1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not actually using each and every field in the rows returned, and you really want to wring every drop of efficiency out of this query, then don't use select *, but instead specify only the fields you want to process.